# A simpler approach to Brezis' Proposition 8.5

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, sobolev-spaces, alternative-proof

I'm reading a result from Brezis' *Functional Analysis*

> **Proposition 8.5.** Let $u \in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ with $1<p<\infty$. The following properties are equivalent:
>
> - (i) $u \in W^{1, p}(\mathbb{R})$,
> - (ii) there exists a constant $C$ such that for all $h \in \mathbb{R}$,
>   $$
>   \|\tau_h u-u\|_{L^p} \leq C|h| .
>   $$
>
> Moreover, one can choose $C=\|u^{\prime}\|_{L^p}$ in (ii).

Recall that $(\tau_h u)(x)=u(x+h)$.The proof of the implication (i) $\implies$ (ii) is given as follows:

> This implication is also valid when $p=1$. By **Theorem 8.2** we have, for all $x$ and $h$ in $\mathbb{R}$,
> $$
> u(x+h)-u(x)=\int_x^{x+h} u^{\prime}(t) d t=h \int_0^1 u^{\prime}(x+s h) d s .
> $$
>
> Thus
> $$
> |u(x+h)-u(x)| \leq|h| \int_0^1\left|u^{\prime}(x+s h)\right| d s .
> $$
>
> Applying Hölder's inequality, we have
> $$
> |u(x+h)-u(x)|^p \leq|h|^p \int_0^1\left|u^{\prime}(x+s h)\right|^p d s .
> $$
>
> It then follows that
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> \int_{\mathbb{R}}|u(x+h)-u(x)|^p d x & \leq|h|^p \int_{\mathbb{R}} d x \int_0^1\left|u^{\prime}(x+s h)\right|^p d s \\
> & \leq|h|^p \int_0^1 d s \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|u^{\prime}(x+s h)\right|^p d x.
> \end{aligned}
> $$
>
> But for $0<s<1$,
> $$
> \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|u^{\prime}(x+s h)\right|^p d x=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|u^{\prime}(y)\right|^p d y,
> $$
>
> from which (ii) can be deduced.

Above proof is non-trivial. On the other hand, it seems I have a found a simpler approach. There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in below attempt. Could you please have a check on it?

---

By **Theorem 8.2** we have, for all $x$ and $h$ in $\mathbb{R}$,
$$
u(x+h)-u(x) = \int_x^{x+h} u^{\prime}(t) d t.
$$

Then
$$
\begin{align*}
\| \tau_h u - u\|_{L^p}^p &= \int_{\mathbb R} \left | \int_x^{x+h} u^{\prime}(t) d t \right |^p dx \\
&= h^p \int_{\mathbb R} \left | \frac{1}{h} \int_x^{x+h} u^{\prime}(t) d t \right |^p dx.
\end{align*}
$$

We need an auxilary result (from the same book):

> [Exercise 4.9](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4671422/brezis-exercise-4-9) (Jensen's inequality) Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mu)$ be a measure space with $\mu(\Omega) < \infty$. Let $J:\mathbb R \to (-\infty, +\infty]$ be a convex lower semi-continuous function such that $j$ is not identically equal to $+\infty$. Let $f \in L^1 (\Omega)$ such that $f(\omega) \in D(J)$ for $\mu$-a.e. $\omega \in \Omega$ and that $J(f) \in L^1 (\Omega)$. Then
> $$
> J \bigg ( \frac{1}{\mu(\Omega)} \int_\Omega f \, \mathrm d \mu \bigg ) \le \frac{1}{\mu(\Omega)} \int_\Omega J \circ f \, \mathrm d \mu.
> $$
> Here $D(J) := \{x \in \mathbb R : f(x) \neq +\infty\}$ is the domain of $J$.

The map $x \mapsto |x|^p$ [is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/849573/composition-of-convex-and-power-function) clearly convex and thus continuous for $p \in [1, \infty)$. WLOG, we assume $h>0$. By **Exercise 4.9**, we get
$$
\left | \frac{1}{h} \int_x^{x+h} u^{\prime}(t) d t \right |^p \le \frac{1}{h} \int_x^{x+h} |u^{\prime}(t)|^p d t.
$$

Then
$$
\begin{align*}
\| \tau_h u - u\|_{L^p}^p &\le h^{p-1} \int_{\mathbb R} \int_x^{x+h} |u^{\prime}(t)|^p d t dx \\
&= h^{p-1} \int_\mathbb R \left ( \int_{t-h}^t dx \right ) |u^{\prime}(t)|^p dt \quad \text{by Fubini's theorem} \\
&= h^{p} \|u'\|_{L^p}^p.
\end{align*}
$$

This completes the proof.

Comment: Your proof is OK +1. In fact, your proof and Brezis's proof are essentially along the same track. Your application of Jensen's inequality can alternatively be obtained using Hölder's inequality, just as in Brezis's proof: $$\left|\int_x^{x+h}u'(t)\,dt\right|\leq \left(\int_x^{x+h}|u'(t)|^p\,dt\right)^{1/p}h^{1/p'},$$ with $\frac1{p'}=1-\frac1p$, hence $$\left|\frac1h\int_x^{x+h}u'(t)\,dt\right|^p\leq h^{\frac p{p'}-p}\int_x^{x+h}|u'(t)|^p\,dt=\frac1h\int_x^{x+h}|u'(t)|^p\,dt.$$